# MVC processing database actions model vs controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating my first MVC project, although not new to coding.  According to Microsoft:

*An MVC model contains all of your application logic that is not contained in a view or a controller. The model should contain all of your application business logic, validation logic, and database access logic. For example, if you are using the Microsoft Entity Framework to access your database, then you would create your Entity Framework classes (your .edmx file) in the Models folder.
A view should contain only logic related to generating the user interface. A controller should only contain the bare minimum of logic required to return the right view or redirect the user to another action (flow control). Everything else should be contained in the model.
In general, you should strive for fat models and skinny controllers. Your controller methods should contain only a few lines of code. If a controller action gets too fat, then you should consider moving the logic out to a new class in the Models folder.*

At first I wrote all database logic in the controller class. I have successfully re-written a majority of it in the model class but there are major problems with this approach that I would like to get cleared up.

First of all is all the UrlHelper / HttpRequestBase / HttpContext / ModelStateDictionary, all of these functions are part of you controller class.  It was written as though you are supposed to do most of this processing in the controller class.

For example my controller class once you register a new account:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (accountModel.register(model, Url, Request, ModelState) == true)
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
     return View(model);
}
```

And my model class:

```
public bool register(RegisterViewModel model, UrlHelper url, HttpRequestBase request, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (userManager.FindByEmail(model.Email) != null)
        {
            modelState.AddModelError("Email", "Error, already have this email registered!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            MyIdentityUser user = new MyIdentityUser();

            user.Email = model.Email;
            user.FullName = model.FullName;
            user.UserName = model.Email;

            IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ReadOnly");

                string code = userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: request.Url.Scheme);
                userManager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking" + System.Environment.NewLine + "<a style=\"border:15px solid #00FF00;background-color:#00FF00;color:#000;font-size:14px; font-family:Arial;text-decoration:none\" href =\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                modelState.AddModelError("Email", "Error while creating the user!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this model class, I have no access to the ModelState, UrlHelper, HttpRequestBase since they are all part of the controller class.

Am I supposed to be passing all these variables into my model class to have access to them?  Seems like Microsoft wrote this to do all the logic in the controller even though they state not to.  Just dont really see why not to do it in the controller to not have to pass all these variables to the model class.

Comment: Ooh, no. The way I like to conceptualize it is we have entity models that we use to communicate with the database (via Entity Framework). These are POCO classes. Controllers go out and fetch our entities and we fill a ViewModel for our specific need (add an invoice for example). Then we call our view with the ViewModel and when the form is posted back we validate and save. See this https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/24/how-we-do-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

MVC has nothing to do with Microsoft - it is a concept that was around 20 years ago. Seriously.

Yes, Models are that - Models. VERY little logic happens in them (MOSTLY: NONE) and when I see your view, I see way too much code. It is not a model.

The reason you have no access to all those variables in the model is that you do not need them. You should not do any processing that is not about presenting data in the Model. Which you do.

Comment: So should I be doing this logic in the actual controller POST class?  Even if I make a service class, it will be similar to this model class because it won't be part of the controller and it won't have access to those variables.  This is what I was going off of... 

Your controller methods should contain only a few lines of code. If a controller action gets too fat, then you should consider moving the logic out to a new class in the Models folder.

Comment: Depends on how often you do it - noone says the controller has to do all the work itself. You also can make a model have submodels and have them render via subviews (for repeating elements) or use inheritance here. Just keep the models "stupid" with as little logic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the quote you gave, "Model" refers to Entity Framework models, i.e. domain logic.

A **View**Model should only be concerned with display logic, e.g. preprocessing some data retrieved from the backend before displaying it. The right place to put your `Register` method is the Controller or some Application / Domain Service called by the Controller.

Create a new MVC project from template in Visual Studio, and have a look at the AccountController to see how MS implements the user registration.

Answer (score 0):

The View is what is used to "View" the results... It is told what to display from the "Controller", and the controller gets the information on how to build the data from the Model...

Like so...

First, we need to define your table in the Model...

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }   
}
```

Get your data, make any modifications to it in the Controller...

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();            //Set the context for your DB
    var dataToPassToView = db.MyTable.ToList();  //Get your data from the DB

    //Make any changes/calculations to your data before passing it to the view...

    return View(dataToPassToView);               //Return the View along with your data
}
```

And the View...

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyTable>   //Tell the view what model to use
///Some Code in here to display your data...
```

As you can see, the Model is only defining the data structure. The Controller "controls" the data before it is displayed... and the View takes the finished product from the Controller, and displays it as instructed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)'s an argument for putting your business logic in Model classes. tldr; Data-logic coupling is what Object orientation was invented for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).